# Is there a JToolBar replacement that offers more functionality?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

I'm creating a simple Swing application, then I realized that JToolBar doesn't provide much functionality. For example, I want to add multiple dragable toolbars onto one JFrame, but but I can only have one floatable JToolBar per JFrame if I use JToolbar.

I know that NetBeans is built with Swing, and the toolbars on NetBeans have more functionality then JToolBars. I haven't spent my time to take a peak at NetBeans source yet, but I"m wondering whether there's any other existing replacement for JToolBar out int the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try Kirill's Flamingo (Swing version of Microsoft's Ribbon style toolbar):

Project: https://flamingo.dev.java.net/

Answer (score 1):

JIDE have a component called CommandBar, part of their Action set. I'm not sure if it meets your needs, but (like all JIDE's stuff) it's worth checking out.

http://www.jidesoft.com/products/action.htm

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- I believe that a JToolBar can contain some other JToolBar components.
- You could have a panel at the north
  side which would contain couple of
  JToolBars too.
- Another solution would be to implement your own component or look for commercial alternatives(or dual licensed GPL/Commercial).